# Distribute raws in multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called 'MyTable' that looks like:

```
ID | Item | Type | Value
1  | 100  | 60   | 37
2  | 100  | 72   | 24
3  | 200  | 60   | 18
4  | 300  | 60   | 43
5  | 300  | 72   | 76
```

And I would like to put together an MS SQL query to obtain the following:

```
Item | Type_60 | Type_72
100  | 37      | 24
200  | 18      | NULL
300  | 43      | 76
```

most probably I am not allowed to use PIVOT (that anyway I did not understand how to use for this purpose!).

So far I could only come out with the following:

```
select Item,
    CASE Type WHEN 60 THEN Value END as 'Type_60',
    CASE Type WHEN 72 THEN Value END as 'Type_72'
from MyTable
```

but this gives me the following:

```
Item | Type_60 | Type_72
100  | 37      | NULL
100  | NULL    | 24
200  | 18      | NULL
300  | 43      | NULL
300  | NULL    | 76
```

Can anyone hlep me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, just add `group by Item` at the end, and wrap the `case` in an aggregate:

```
select Item,
    max(CASE Type WHEN 60 THEN Value END) as 'Type_60',
    max(CASE Type WHEN 72 THEN Value END) as 'Type_72'
from MyTable
group by Item
```

Comment: With the group by I get an error: `Column 'Type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`... I will try to learn the basics of group by...

Comment: You're right, I should have added an aggregate like `min` or `max` or `avg`.  Answer updated